# Is it possible to use C++ for network programming in a Flutter app?

Tags: android, c++, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a mobile app with Dart and Flutter. But, trying to use C++ for networking.

Q1: Is it possible to use C++ for socket programming, in a Flutter app?

Q2: Does it run natively as C++ compiled code, or Flutter compiles it into Java/Swift in the final application.

I haven't worked with flutter before (neither native Android/IOS), so this might be a naive question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `dart:io` classes for UDP, TCP and TLS sockets?

Comment: I have already written some code for data encryption in C++. So, I directly wanted to implement encryption and data upload at one go.

Comment: Unless it's immensely complicated you might want to port the C++ code to Dart. There's a fairly comprehensive suite of standard cryptography components in the `pointycastle` package you could leverage. Dart compiles to native code in release mode. There's a chance that that's less complex than learning `dart:ffi`. To answer your questions: Q1 - my guess would be no (or take a lot of work), but try it. Q2 - using ffi it would run natively in the Dart threads, which are different from the native Java/Swift threads. See also: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/The-Engine-architecture

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [`dart:ffi`](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop) (foreign function interface) to interface with native C++ code.

[Learn more](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop).

Comment: Upvoting because I didn't know what ffi meant. Thanks

Comment: Sure, you might use ffi for some existing, computationally expensive C code (e.g. codec, encryption, image processing) but what would be the advantage for sockets? If you need native specific features (e.g. binding to a particular NIC) wouldn't you use a plugin to access the Android/iOS specific features?

Comment: @RichardHeap Sure, the Dart implementations should be fine as well.